# Can I have nested defmethod/defgeneric in lisp?

Tags: scope, lisp, let

I want to create the equivalent of a "nested `LET`" as in Haskell, where I can refer to some values bound in the outer `LET`. The caveat is that the function defined in the inner scope needs to dispatch on the type of its argument, so `defgeneric` came to mind.

Now this is my confusion: I have only ever defined this at "top level" (at package scope); is it possible to define it within an arbitrary lexical context ?

If not, is there a recommended alternative ? One hacky solution would be to pass the "context" as a `defstruct` argument to the function, I'm hoping there's something better ?

(I hope my intent is not lost in translation!)

**Edit:** This was a stupid question, I should have just tried it. In case someone looks for the answer to this, it is YES, and also "of course", (duh)

As a simple example,

```
(let ((x 4))  
      (defgeneric bar (y))  
      (defmethod bar ((y integer)) (1+ y))  
      (bar x))
```

evaluates to

```
5
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, this turned out to be a stupid question. I should have just tried it. I'll edit the question and mark it resolved.

Comment: Hmm I can't answer my question for 8 hours apparently, so I'll just have to edit it and leave it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. It has a few downsides.

- `DEFMETHOD` and `DEFGENERIC` are top-level forms. This means that the file compiler recognizes them and then knows about them. Inside a `LET`, these forms are no longer top-level forms and the compiler does not recognize them.
- It makes debugging harder. Suddenly there is a context for methods.
- It makes updating methods harder. I can't not just evaluate a `DEFMETHOD` form to update the method, I would also need to evaluate the context.

There are two typical ways to use a context at runtime:

1. Use a dynamic binding at runtime
2. Use a parameter at runtime

Example for 1:

```
(let ((*user* (find-current-user)))
  (declare (special *user*))
  (serve-page ...))
```

Alternatively the *special* variable could be declared global.

Example for 2:

```
(serve-page ... :user (find-current-user))
```

Even a plain package local variable can be good enough...

Comment: Thanks! So if the context here consists of (say) several values that I would have bound in the `LET` clause, would you suggest wrapping them up in a struct ?